# How does the configuration work for the content section in tailwind config file?

Tags: javascript, path, config, tailwind-css, vite

Im setting up tailwind in a react project bundled with Vite, and am wanted to be sure of how to set up the config file content array. The docs have this code snippet below, and I was wondering if theres a resource explaining how this works, what its called, etc, specifically with the `./src/**/*/{..}` part. Thanks.

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration

It uses [fast-glob](https://github.com/mrmlnc/fast-glob) to find which files it needs to scan for Tailwind classes.

```
"./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"
```

This will match all files in the `src` directory, including any files in sub-folders, with file extensions of `js`, `ts`, `jsx` or `tsx`.